# three simple Ajax/php security questions

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security, class

Hoping someone with technical knowledge can answer these the questions for me:

1. I've tried before, and I'm led to believe that php classes cannot be used in a jQuery Ajax call. Is this true, Or is there a way of making it work?
2. If the above is not possible, is there any way of using protected/private functions and variables without classes? Again, I believe this isn't possible, but would love to be proved wrong.
3. Is the above all even necessary, when the data is passed over https and is salted and hashed server side anyway?

Comment: **I'm led to believe that php classes cannot be used in a jQuery Ajax call.** used in what way?

Comment: Classes, functions, whatever, does'nt matter, the script will do exactly what it's supposed to do, ajax or no ajax. Classes won't really make your site secure either, neither will hashing arbitrary data. Make sure you validate user input and have a secure server, and most of the time you'll be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 . I've tried before, and I'm led to believe that php classes cannot be
>   used in a jQuery Ajax call. Is this true, Or is there a way of making
>   it work?

False. Many many people use PHP pages to answer ajax requests. in fact any server-side technologies able to answer an HTTP request can be used to provide AJAX content, usually in JSON or XML. Her's the first hit Google gave me : [Handling JSON like a boss in PHP](http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP)

> 2 . If the above is not possible, is there any way of using protected/private functions and variables without classes? Again, I
>   believe this isn't possible, but would love to be proved wrong.

Not relevant as the above is possible.

> 3 . Is the above all even necessary, when the data is passed over
>   https and is salted and hashed server side anyway?

I'm not sure of your exact meaning but AJAX over HTTPS provides authentication and secrecy. Provided your solution is correctly configured, which is very very rare...

You should understand that

- the essence of AJAX is answering (usually in JSON) javascript made requests made over HTTP just like your usual html page, and PHP can very well do that.
- PHP objects may be serialized as JSOn for the browser but the PHP code doesn't leave the server. Your private or public functions are all safe : nobody will see the implementation. But I hope your business or security doesn't really rely on this code not leaking. Regarding the client side javascript code needed to handle the logic of the objects, it can't be protected : if a browser can read it, a human can do it too.

Comment: Straight in, json_ encode is the piece I'm missing, everything is server side so your answer to point three does lead me to believe that it won't be necessary, but I'll have a look into this in more detail later. Cheers for the great link

Answer (score 1):

1. It's possible. You can use them. It depends how you want to use them. There is article how to do that with Zend http://blog.mysql.lt/ajax-aplikacijos-su-zend_json_server.html but it's in lithuanian.

Further dystroy answers...

--

You can use PHP reflection classes for that. It's very easy to implament use of php methods in  javascript.